# Ruby Seed - How to store subcategories for each sneaker and remove duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, seed

I want to create my database from CSV data. For that I have parse my file and I start to seed.

In my .csv file, there are sneakers name with subcategories like in the picture :

In my db/seeds.rb, i coded this :

```
# db/seeds.rb
csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'air_jordan.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
air_jordan_subcategories = ['1', '11', "Jordan OFF-WHITE", "Future", "Women", "High"]
csv.each do |row|
  s = Sneaker.new
  s.name = row['Name']  
  air_jordan_subcategories.each do |sub|
    if row['Subcategory'] == sub
        s.subcategory << sub
    end
  end
  s.save
end
```

What I want is that the pair “Jordan 1 Mid Banned (2020)“, appears like this in my database:

```
=> #<Sneaker:0x00007ffdbd4a5980 
id: 1,
name: "Jordan 1 Mid Banned (2020)",
subcategory : ["Mid", "1"]>
```

While for the moment, in my database I have 2 times the same pair because I have 2 different subcategories :

```
=> #<Sneaker:0x00007ffdbd4a5980 
id : 1,
name : "Jordan 1 Mid Banned (2020)",
subcategory : ["Mid"]>
=> #<Sneaker:0x00007ffdbd4a5933 
id: 2,
name : "Jordan 1 Mid Banned (2020)",
subcategory : ["1"] >
```

I can’t find a logical solution for this, what I would like is simply :

```
 air_jordan_subcategories.each do |sub|
    while row['category'] == sub
        s.subcategory << sub
        row += 1
    end
  end
```

But row += 1 doesn’t work, and while row['category'] == sub trigger an infinite loop.
Thanks for helping ![image]

Comment: What should the `insert`ed `subcategory` be based on? The CSV `Name` or the CSV `Subcategory`? Can you show the one relevant line from your CSV?